# URL(string:) gives nil error even if the String is not nil in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, null, qr-code

I have the following code:

```
print("CODE STRING SELECTED: \(codeString)")
let aURL = URL(string: codeString)!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(aURL) { UIApplication.shared.openURL(aURL) }
```

This code is inside a Button and the Xcode console prints the `codeString` correctly, it's not `nil` and so it should open the URL of the `codeString`, instead, Xcode throws this error:

```
CODE STRING SELECTED: mailto:john@doe.com?subject=Subject here&body=Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet quatum.

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2019-07-08 11:19:56.076467+0200 QRcode[2751:1043394] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The same thing happens in case of a Phone number or SMS string (I get the `codeString` value from a scanned QR code):

```
CODE STRING SELECTED: tel:+1 2345678901
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

CODE STRING SELECTED: SMSTO:+1012345678:lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

In case of a URL, like https//example.com, the app doesn't crash, no nil error, same for text, etc. So I really don't understand why I get that error even if the `codeString` is not `nil`.

Comment: Have you considered doing a guard let to confirm that it is not nil by the time you’re accessing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string is not `nil` but it does not represent a valid URL. You have to encode the URL.

However it's recommended to unwrap the optionals safely

```
if let encodedString = codeString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
   let aURL = URL(string: encodedString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(aURL) { 
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(aURL) 
}
```

**Update 2023:**

From the documentation of [`URL(string:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3126806-init?changes=latest_minor)

> **Important:**
> For apps linked on or after iOS 17 and aligned OS versions, URL parsing has updated from the obsolete RFC 1738/1808 parsing to the same RFC 3986 parsing as URLComponents. This unifies the parsing behaviors of the URL and URLComponents APIs. Now, URL automatically percent- and IDNA-encodes invalid characters to help create a valid URL.

Comment: You're right, @vadian, thanks so much for your help, I'll accept your answer

Comment: Wonderful solution!

Answer (score 0):

The url is `nil` because it cannot be created without escaping spaces you got there.

This would work:

```
guard let escapedString = codeString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: urlQuoeryAllowed), 
      let url = URL(string: escapedString) else {
 return
}
```